# Azure DevOps pipeline: how to find name of ZIP file crated by botnet publish?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to build, publish, and deploy a bot web app to Azure (App Service).
I'm unable to get the pipeline to work. YAML below.

The solution has two `cpsproj` files: `IMB.csproj` and `Client.csproj` where IMB references Client. I'm only interested in building and publishing IMB.

The build process shows the error:

> ##[error]Error: More than one package matched with specified pattern: D:\a\1\s***.zip. Please restrain the search pattern.

- Why is there more than one ZIP file?
- What is the path/name of the ZIP file belonging to IMB.csproj?

```yaml
name: Build and deploy IMB

trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build bot web app'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/IMB.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration Release'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Publish bot web app'
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '**/IMB.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration Release'

- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  displayName: 'Deploy ZIP to Azure'
  inputs:
    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
    azureSubscription: 'IMB (12...)'
    appType: 'webApp'
    WebAppName: 'imb'
    packageForLinux: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip'
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is: if the option to "Zip after publish" is enabled, the filename used is based on the project names (omitting the `.csproj` extension). In my case, the filename is `IMB.zip`